# Why do I get a 'conformability error' when I attempt to convert water in GNU units?

Tags: utilities

I've been using the GNU units program and I seem to think that I should be able to convert water between a volume and a weight.

Examples:

```
You have: 1 gram water
You want: cm^3
conformability error
    1 gram water = 9.80665 kg^2 / m^2 s^2
    cm^3 = 1e-06 m^3
```

and

```
You have: 1 gallon water
You want: pounds
conformability error
    1 gallon water = 37.122208 kg m / s^2
    pounds = 0.45359237 kg
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `water` unit is the [specific weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_weight) of water at the [standard temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_temperature) of 0°C. A `cm water` is a unit of pressure, like the `cm Hg`.

```
You have: water
You want: 
        Definition: gram force/cm^3 = 9806.65 kg / m^2 s^2

You have: 1cm Hg
You want: cm water
        * 13.5951
        / 0.073555914
```

A `gram water` is a unit of mass times pressume divided by length, which I don't recognize as a common physical quantity. Units has `waterdensity` defined to be the density of water at 4°C and 1atm, which is (to a very good precision) 1kg/m³.

```
You have: 1g/waterdensity
You want: cm^3
        * 1
        / 1
```

If you want density in other conditions or of other materials, either type out the constant or put it in your own unit definition file (`units -f '' -f ~/.units.data`).

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, you're trying to convert volume into mass or weight.  Sure, you wrote "water", but at what temperature and pressure?  It makes a difference.  And what if you wrote "1 gram mercury"?

You're asking for something that can't be done in the simplistic context in which `units` works.  I think you're going to have to look up the density of the fluid you're interested in, and multiply by yourself.

Comment: -1, GNU `units` does actually have a limited selection of densities in its database, it's just that the keyword is `waterdensity`, not `water`.